# Can't add text field to static table view

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to add a Text Field to a static cell in a Table View Controller. When I drag the Text Field to the cell it won't stay.
I'm using Xcode 7.

Comment: Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of cell from  `static` to `prototype`.

In the storyboard, click on table view, on the right side inspector, there is provision to change the type of cell.